# Парсинг сайта при помощи bs4

Tags: python, html, парсер, bs4

Как мне задать ключ для парсинга в `find`, чтобы получить какие-либо данные?

У меня имеется такой html:

```
<a data-toggle="popover7067" id="bx_3966226736_7067_secondpict" href="/remen-bezopasnosti-2-go-ryada-sideniy-lev-prav-blk-tesla-model-3-1081281-01-f/" title="1 Ремень безопасности 2-го ряда сидений лев. прав. (BLK) Tesla model 3 1081281-01-F">
                                    
                                        <!-- <div id="img7067"> -->

                                        
        <div class="lazy b_red1" data-bg="url(/upload/resize_cache/iblock/f5d/250_250_1/f5d1f9f364cc3b5265d8b8c93751c7fe.jpeg)" style="background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: contain; height: 250px; width: auto; margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top: 10px; background-image: url(&quot;/upload/resize_cache/iblock/f5d/250_250_1/f5d1f9f364cc3b5265d8b8c93751c7fe.jpeg&quot;);" data-was-processed="true">
        </div>                                        <!-- </div> -->
                                    </a>
```

Мне необходимо задать в find ключ `data-toggle` со значением `popover7067`, чтобы получить информацию. Я знаю, что я мог бы указать просто тег `а` и получить всё что угодно, но для меня важно разобраться как работать с таким ключом как `data-toggle`, потому что нередко при парсинге разных сайтов появляются ключи с рисочкой, буду благодарен за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Решение довольно просто, вам просто нужно больше по гуглить, и научится читать документации.

Здесь в качестве фильтра используем словарь в котором указываем атрибуте тега в качестве ключа, а его значение в качестве значения атрибута. Шаблон выглядеть будет так.

```py
element = soup.find("tag", {"key" : "value"})
```

Ну а в вашем примере, выглядеть будет так

```py
element = soup.find("a", {"data-toggle" : "popover7067"})
```

Такой же стиль можно использовать когда вам нужно найти все элементы

```py
elements = soup.find_all("a", {"data-toggle" : "popover7067"})
```